# Combinations sum depth first search solution

Tags: algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

Given a list of positive integers and a target value, generate a solution set. For example, if the list is `[10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5]` and the target is `8`, the solution set is...

```
[
    [1, 7],
    [1, 2, 5],
    [2, 6]
    [1, 1, 6]
[
```

I know there a multiple solutions to this, such as dp, but I am trying to get my dfs solution working and I believe I am very close, but I simply cannot get the correct result. If possible, I would like it if you didn't change my initial answer too much, if that's not possible, any solution will do.

```
def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
    candidates.sort()
    total = []
    self.helper(candidates, 0, target, [], total)

def helper(self, candidates, curr, target, temp, total):
    if target == 0:
        total.append(temp)
        return

    if target < 0:
        return

    for i in range(curr, len(candidates)):
        # avoid duplicates
        if i > curr and candidates[i] == candidates[i-1]:
            continue
        temp.append(candidates[i])
        self.helper(candidates, i+1, target-candidates[i], temp, total)
        # I'm not sure what to do here
```

This obviously does not give me the right result but I do think I am on the right track towards generating the solution set. I simply do not understand what I need to do after the recursive call to remove unnecessary elements.

Comment: I presume you're familiar with the knapsack problem?   In any case,why skip duplicates? if your `target=5`, and your `candidates=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` is that not a valid solution?  Where your final comment is, I think you should also try recursing without adding `candidates[i]` to `temp`.  Otherwise, how will your algorithm skip a candidate?  Consider `target=5` and `candidates = [4, 8, 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is along the lines of what you are trying to do:

```
def solve(target, sum, candidates, answer):
    if sum == target:
        print answer
        return

    if len(candidates) == 0 or sum > target:
        return

    first = candidates[0]
    count = candidates.count(first);

    answer.append(first)
    solve(target, sum+first, candidates[1:], answer)  #using the current number
    answer.pop()
    solve(target, sum, candidates[count:], answer)    #skipping the current number and any duplicates

if __name__ == "__main__":
    candidates = [10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5]
    candidates.sort();
    solve(8, 0, candidates, [])
```

The key point is that `solve` has two recursive calls.

The first recursive call uses the first number in the `candidates` list. So it

1. appends the first number to the answer
2. adds the first number to the `sum`
3. removes only the first number from the candidates list that is
   passed to the next level

The second recursive call doesn't use the first number in the `candidates` list. And since it doesn't use the first number, it also doesn't use any duplicates of the first number. That's the reason for the `count` variable. `candidates.count(first)` is the number of entries in the list that are equal to `first`. So in the recursive call `candidates[count:]` removes the `first` element and any duplicates. (This assumes that the list is sorted, which should be done once before calling `solve`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution using recursion – I chose a tuple to represent the combinations, but you could've used list for those too

```py
def combinationSum (l, target, sum = 0, comb = ()):

  # base case: empty input [l]
  if not l:
    return []

  # inductive case: [l] has at least one element
  else:

    # [x] is the first sub-problem
    # [xs] is the rest of the sub-problems
    x, *xs = l

    # [x] plus [sum] is bigger than [target]
    if x + sum > target:
      return \
        combinationSum (xs, target, sum, comb)

    # [x] plus [sum] is smaller than [target]
    elif x + sum < target:
      return \
        combinationSum (xs, target, sum + x, (x, *comb)) + \
        combinationSum (xs, target, sum, comb)

    # [x] plus [sum] is equal to [target]
    else:
      return \
        [ (x, *comb)  ] + \
        combinationSum (xs, target, sum + x, (x, *comb)) + \
        combinationSum (xs, target, sum, comb)
```

```py
data = [10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5]
```

```py
print (combinationSum (data, 8))
# [(5, 2, 1), (7, 1), (1, 6, 1), (6, 2), (5, 1, 2), (1, 7)]
```

If you want `combinationSum` to allow for duplicate values, you only have to change one part. Note, the program considers eg `(5, 1, 1, 1)` a solution 3 times because the 1 appears in 3 unique positions. If you only wanted `(5, 1, 1, 1)` to appear once, you'd have to consider a different approach.

```py
...
    elif x + sum < target:
      return \
        combinationSum (xs, target, sum + x, (x, *comb)) + \
        combinationSum (l , target, sum + x, (x, *comb)) + \
        combinationSum (xs, target, sum, comb)
...
```

```py
print (combinationSum (data, 8))
```

```py
[ (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (5, 1, 1, 1)
, (2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
, (6, 1, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (5, 1, 1, 1)
, (1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)
, (5, 2, 1)
, (7, 1)
, (1, 6, 1)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (5, 1, 1, 1)
, (2, 2, 2, 2)
, (1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
, (6, 2)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
, (5, 1, 2)
, (1, 7)
, (1, 1, 6)
, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, (5, 1, 1, 1)]
]
```